# What are the embedded databases for react native apps

Tags: database, react-native

Need to embed a pre-populated database to react native application.
EX: Mobile application which read and display texts from the database. Database is pre-populated and embedded into the application. which does not have connection with any other server or api.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is static you can store the data as plan JSON in source code. Otherwise you can use [Async Storage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) or [SQLite](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage).